# How to retrieve nested data in listview from firebase in android

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve nested data from firebase in listview but the output is not correct. The output is "com.example.packagename". I want to retrieve customerName, date and productName at the given location. I also attached the user model class. According to my thinking the setkey() method retrieve the first key in which current register user place his/her order against his/her UID and internal keys are get from firebase pushkey() method.

[image: Database]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sales_report);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<UserModel>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        MyRef = database.getReference("placedOrders");

        MyRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
                for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    userModel = dsp.getValue(UserModel.class);
                    userModel.setKey(dsp.getKey());

                    arrayList.add(userModel);
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
```

This is my user model class.

```
public class UserModel {

    private String customerName;
    private String productName;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private Date date;
    private String key;

    public UserModel(){

    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        date = date;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        productName = productName;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't immediately see what's going wrong. Does you `UserModel` class match the JSON? Note btw, that your `userModel.setKey(dsp.getKey())` is overwritten by the next line. I don't think that is the cause of your problem, but you should swap the lines anywy.

Comment: I was run it by swap the lines but output is same "com.example.packagename". I have enter some more detail in question. Please read and help me.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you shared. That looks fine to me. How do you actually display the values? I.e. how does you `ViewHolder` get the value from the object and set them on the views?

Comment: I want to display customerName, productName and date in listview.

Comment: Understood. How do you currently show them? What does your view holder look like?